# Same username and email for both github and bitbucket account

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, repo

Hi I share the same username and email for my github and bitbucket account . Now I have configured git on my linux pc with the below commands

```
    $ git config --global user.name "user name"
    $ git config --global user.email "email"
```

As I have same username and email for github and bitbucket which account will work in this case ? How will push and pull work ? Is there a way to use both accounts at same time ?

Comment: These two settings are *only used when making commits* and control the text strings that Git puts in the new commit's metadata. **These are not used for authentication.** Authentication on GitHub and BItbucket uses https and/or ssh, not Git.

Answer (score 2):

Both account will work without any problem but you should configure the remote link for Github and Bitbucket for example for github account:

> `git remote add github https://github.com/username/repositoryName.git`

And push to github

> `git push github master`

For bitbucket account:

`git remote add bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/workspace/repositoryName.git`

And push to bitbucket:

> `git push bitbucket master`

Comment: Okay good to know . So I can push the same local repo to both accounts with the above commands ? will the pull command also work the same way ? I am new to these so probably confused .

Comment: @Nayan In Github account llink ``https://github.com/username/repositoryName.git`` you will change ``username`` to your ``username`` and  ``repositoryName.git`` to ``your repositoryName`` on Github and same style to Bitbucket remote link

Comment: @Nayan For pull command  you will use this command ``git pull github master`` and for bitbucket you will use ``git pull bitbucket master``